How to split a List<String > values and get only numbers into another list
I am having List values as  ["12-dept20","13-dept50"]
i want to split these to a list with only the numbers before - , to get a List as [12, 13]
List. split using streams , but not sure on how to work on it. Any help would be appreciated.
I am using java 8
List src = ["12-dept20","13-dept50"];
Expected:
List new = [12, 13]

Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for the question. My guess is your question was closed because you didn’t clearly enough demonstrate your own effort trying to solve it. Most of us here are much happier with an account of your search results and your attempt to write the code, and we will enjoy helping you fix it so it works.

Here you go:
List<String> source = List.of("12-dept20", "13-dept50");

List<Integer> target = source.stream()
        .map(entry -> entry.split("-")[0])
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .toList();

System.out.println(target);

Bear in mind that this code is not failsafe, in case the entries cannot be parsed due to missformat.

Answer
List<String> src = List.of("12-dept20", "13-dept50");
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String str : src) {
    String[] parts = str.split("-");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    result.add(number);
}
System.out.println(result);


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> inputList = Arrays.asList("12-dept20", "13-dept50");
        List<String> outputList = extractNumbersBeforeDash(inputList);
        System.out.println(outputList); // output: [12, 13]
    }

    public static List<String> extractNumbersBeforeDash(List<String> lst) {
        List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String s : lst) {
            int dashIndex = s.indexOf('-'); // Find the location of the dash
            if (dashIndex != -1) { // If a dash is found
                numbers.add(s.substring(0, dashIndex)); // Extract the part before the dash
            } else {
                // If there is no dash in the string, it can be processed according to the requirements. Here, it is simply skipped
                System.err.println("No dash found in string: " + s);
            }
        }
        return numbers;
    }
}

